# Replica Set in MongoDB by using IPs instead of domains?

Tags: mongodb

I want to use MongoDB in replica-set mode over 2 servers by IPs.But when I deployed the secondary one on other server, I faced the issues about connecting between 2 instance. For example, the primary located on server 192.168.1.1:27018 with hostname COM1 and the second located on server 192.168.1.2:27018 with hostname COM2. Despite of configuring like this

```
net:
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0, COM1|192.168.1.1, COM2|192.168.1.2
    port: 27018
```

But in MongoDB's log, it responses that cant hear from COM1:27018 or can find COM2:27018, I don't know how to map these addresses with these IPs. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: The `bindIp` directive specifies the network interface(s) `mongod` should *listen* for connections on: those IP addresses have to be local to the `mongod` environment. It looks like you are trying to specify remote IPs and hostname mapping for other members of your replica set -- this syntax is not valid. Hostname to IP mapping is handled by standard DNS resolution, which is configured in your O/S and not part of the MongoDB server configuration. There are plenty of tutorials for setting up DNS, but if you are having trouble finding details Server Fault would be more appropriate for questions.

Comment: Since the MongoDB configuration syntax you've provided should result in a startup error, I'm guessing the errors you mention in the MongoDB log relate to the hostnames you used when creating your replica set config. If the names `COM1` and `COM2` are not resolvable, you can use `rs.reconfig()` to update your replica set configuration using IPs instead of hostnames. If you are still having difficulty, please edit your question to include the output of `rs.conf()`.

Answer (score 0):

From your primary machine run the following command

```
mongo --host COM2 --port 27018
```

You should be able to connect to the MongoDB running in the secondary node using the above command. If it fails to connect, check the following configuration settings

1. Check the `bindIp` settings of the secondary node configuration file, it should allow connection from `192.168.1.1:27018`.
2. Check the port number `27018` is accepting [inbound connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/26564/how-to-check-if-a-port-is-blocked-on-a-windows-machine) in the secondary node. If not add an entry in [IP Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606582/how-to-open-port-2195-in-iptables-centos-6-for-activating-the-apns).
3. Check if secondary nodes [hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339248/append-line-to-etc-hosts-file-with-shell-script) file is updated with primary machines DNS name
   and IP Address.

Follow the same for Primary node as well and try to connect to each machine from other machine using the first command. If everything working fine you should be able to set up your replica set.

Answer (score 0):

> Replica Set in MongoDB by using IPs instead of domains?

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) To override and bind to other ip addresses, you can use the  [net.bindIp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) configuration file setting or the `--bind_ip` command-line option to specify a list of hostnames or ip addresses.

**`For example`**, the following mongod instance binds to both the localhost and the hostname My-Example-Associated-Hostname, which is associated with the ip address 198.51.100.1:

```
mongod --bind_ip localhost,My-Example-Associated-Hostname
```

In order to connect to this instance, remote clients must specify the hostname or its associated ip address 198.51.100.1:

```
mongo --host My-Example-Associated-Hostname

mongo --host 198.51.100.1
```

Ensure that network traffic can pass securely between all members of the set and all clients in the network .

Consider the following:

- Establish a virtual private network. Ensure that your network
  topology routes all traffic between members within a single site over
  the local area network.
- Configure access control to prevent connections from unknown clients
  to the replica set.
- Configure networking and firewall rules so that incoming and outgoing
  packets are permitted only on the default MongoDB port and only from
  within your deployment. See the IP Binding considerations.

> **WARNING NOTE:** Before binding to a non-localhost (e.g. publicly accessible) IP address, ensure you have secured your cluster from
>   unauthorized access. For a complete list of security recommendations,
>   see Security
>   Checklist. At minimum, consider enabling
>   authentication and hardening
>   network infrastructure.

If you will specifies the replica set name and the ip binding through the --replSet and --bind_ip command-line options:

```
mongod --replSet "rs0" --bind_ip localhost,<hostname(s)|ip address(es)>
```

For , specify the hostname(s) and/or ip address(es) for your mongod instance that remote clients (including the other members of the replica set) can use to connect to the instance.

Alternatively, you can also specify the [replica set name](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replication.replSetName) and the  [ip addresses](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) in a [configuration file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/):

```
replication:
   replSetName: "rs0"
net:
   bindIp: localhost,<hostname(s)|ip address(es)>
```

> **Note:** Changed in version 3.6: Starting in MongoDB 3.6, MongoDB binaries, mongod and mongos, bind to localhost by default. If the
>   net.ipv6 configuration file setting or the --ipv6 command line option
>   is set for the binary, the binary additionally binds to the localhost
>   IPv6 address.